# Firebase firestore database returns null, the Query Snapshot value is empty but I have data stored on firestore, why is this returning null?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**here is the code I am using:**

```java
database.collection("final")
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            assert value != null;
            Log.d("TAG", "onEvent: "+ value.isEmpty());
            models.clear();
      
            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value.getDocuments()){
                FirebaseModel model = snapshot.toObject(FirebaseModel.class);
                assert model != null;
                models.add(model);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

```
public class FirebaseModel {

    private String image;
    private String title;
    private String detail;

    public FirebaseModel() {
    }

    public FirebaseModel(String image, String title, String detail) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}
```

[image: this is image of firestore database]

The `value.getDocuments();` returns null but I have saved data on firestore database.

```
Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: "+ value.isEmpty());
```

this log returns onEvent: True which means it returns null not the data stored on firebase firestore

Comment: What does `Log.d("TAG", "onEvent: "+ value.isEmpty());` return? Please edit your question and add the content of your `FirebaseModel` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo OP updated their question to provide the info you asked for.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for notifying me. Mujadid, when you say "The value.getDocuments(); returns null", it means that you get a NullPointerException, right?

Comment: Then is you don't get null. What exactly are you getting then?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for your reply! actually value.getDocuments(); returns null means it returns nothing from firebase firestore. Moreover, it does not show any error like NullPointerException.

Comment: So the message in the logcat is `"onEvent: null"`, right?

Comment: the message in the logcat is "onEvent: true"